# Security threats of having huge number of network threads in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to know what security threats are there if I increase the number of network threads to a large number (num.network.threads) in Apache Kafka or in general according to multi-threading concept.

Comment: What do you mean by "security threats"? Why do you think the number of threads has an impact on security?

Comment: My teacher asked me this how can this impact on the software or system security if the multi-threading is not done properly.